# How to add vb webservice in C# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi i am new to C# web services,

I need a clarification. In my company , i was given a webservice url `(http://servicename/psWs/psWs.asmx)` and the methods in this service are writtn in VB.net . But my problem is , i know only C# and i am a beginner in C# , is there a way to create C# Web Service or WCF and call the service reference url in VSTS where the web service url methods is written in VB .net. Can u please help to any solution . Your help is more valuable.

Finally what i am trying to achieve is ,

1.create a wcf C# application or asp.net web application

2.Add the reference url `(http://servicename/psWs/psWs.asmx)` where the methods is written in VB.net

3.Test the web service by giving input and validating the output

Please dont downvote if my question is irrelavant.

Answer (score 4):

Just right click the project (in which you want to add web service reference) and add the web service reference. Language doesn't matters here. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx)

> 1. To add a Web reference to a project In Solution Explorer,
>          right-click the name of the project that you want to add the service
>          to, and then click Add Service Reference. The Add Service Reference
>          dialog box appears.
> 2. In the Add Service Reference dialog box, click
>          the Advanced button. The Service Reference Settings dialog box
>          appears.
> 3. In the Service Reference Settings dialog box, click Add Web
>          Reference. The Add Web Reference dialog box appears.
> 4. In the URL box,
>          enter the URL of the Web service to use. If you do not know the URL,
>          use the links in the browse pane to locate the Web service you want.
> 5. In the Web services found at this URL box, select the Web service to use.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan and Nagarja S